# jQuery: div closes automatically after show

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a text input, where users can enter searchterms. Idea is to present suggestions in a box below that text input, which fades in showing the results.

The box below:

```
<div class="searchResult">
    <ul class="resultSet">

    </ul>                  
</div>
```

Some CSS:

```
.searchResult {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: $search-result-position-top;
    width: $search-input-width+$bx-search-input-padding*2+2;
    left: -1px;
    z-index: 9999999;
    max-height: 10*($search-result-row-height+1.1);
    overflow-y: auto;

    .imgholder img {
        width: $search-result-img-width;
        height: $search-result-img-height;
    }
}
```

What I´m trying to do is working with following jQuery (just a test so far, because it auto-closes):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#search").find("input").on('keyup', function (e)
    {
        var textInput = $("#search").find("input").val();
        if (textInput.length >= 3)
        {
            $("#search").find(".searchResult ul").append('<li class="resultRow"><a>link1</a></li>');
            $("#search").find(".searchResult ul").append('<li class="resultRow"><a>link2</a></li>');
            $("#search").find(".searchResult ul").append('<li class="resultRow"><a>link3</a></li>');
            $("#search").find(".searchResult").show();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

What happens is, that the three links are shown in a box, just like I expect it to. But just after showing the box auto-closes. Using `e.preventDefault();` causes it so hide later, but does not prevent it.

Please help me, I can´t figure out what´s causing it to auto-close.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qun872mu/2/

It works... Ah damn, must be somewhere else...

Comment: in your code, I didn't get any element with `id=search` and your jquery code added event on that element only(`$("#search").find("input")`)

Comment: Yes, see post below.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have posted is not the cause of the problem that you are describing. I have created a fiddle and it works fine:

```
<div id="search">
  <input type=text/>

  <div class="searchResult">
    <ul class="resultSet">

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>

$("#search").find("input").on('keyup', function(e) {
  var textInput = $("#search").find("input").val();
  if (textInput.length >= 3) {
    $("#search").find(".searchResult ul").append('<li class="resultRow"><a>link1</a></li>');
    $("#search").find(".searchResult ul").append('<li class="resultRow"><a>link2</a></li>');
    $("#search").find(".searchResult ul").append('<li class="resultRow"><a>link3</a></li>');
    $("#search").find(".searchResult").show();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/mopzadLq/1/